# error:ERROR parsing XML: unbound prefix in line 2

Tags: xml, android

here is my code...everything should be correct though???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: That is not your entire XML file right. Surely there is more? Post the whole thing because so far that looks correct.

Comment: i figured it out...it turns out one of my android prefixes was spelled  like so: andriod and in eclipse it referred to it as line 2 for some reason

Answer (score 1):

In this code  there is no error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  />
```

But you have to set width and height of any container view.
so this can be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```